# Need to call dojo widget function from normal javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, widget, dijit.form

I am opening the child window from the dojo widget, on close of the child window i need to call the parent window dojo widget function.

is it possible to call the dojo widget function from normal javascript. if possible please share the code snippet.

Comment: it's possible but if you do not provide a small test case, it's going to be hard to show you

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the registry to call a specific dijit widget in the rest of your application.

You can use it requiring module `dijit/registry` ([more info here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/registry.html)).

The `.byId()` function will basically get a reference to a widget from the registry.

After that you can call your function on the widget object.

A pseudo-code example below:

```
require(['dijit/registry'], function(registry){
    var widget = registry.byId('yourWidget');
    widget.callYourFunction();
})
```

Please consider adding a minimum test case in your question, so we can post a more specific answer.

Comment: First thanks for your reply. The child window application is using the normal JavaScript.I think the above code will work in the dojo environment.

Comment: In order to call a method on a widget you need to get it. You can consider make public `dijit/registry` from the parent window so it is available to the child window. So you can run registry.byId() in the child window to actually referencing your widget initiated in the parent. I hope it helps.